# How can I export data from SQL Server 2005 to a SharePoint list in batches?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I was told that this could be done by using SSIS. Can anyone refer me to the right tutorial?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx)

> The SharePoint List Source and Destination Sample available on Codeplex provides an optimized solution with an easy-to-use interface for getting data out of or into a SharePoint list. The sample also includes an API for accomplishing these tasks efficiently outside of SQL Server Integration Services.
>
> To download the adapters themselves, visit the [Microsoft SQL Server Community Samples: Integration Services page on Codeplex](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/).
>
> To review the document, please download the Word document [Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/0/D20E1C5F-72EA-4505-9F26-FEF9550EFD44/SharePoint%20SSIS%20Adapters%202011.docx).